# Black Scholes PDE for call and put option

Tags: python-3.x, computer-science, numerical-methods, differential-equations, quantitative-finance

So I am trying to implement this PDE so I can obtain the price of a call and put option at t=0.I am having trouble setting up my parameters for stepsize and time step size. Would I need to create a mesh? or Would I need to make another axis?

Comment: Do you want to price American or European options?